# Traceback (most recent call last) error appears on terminal

Tags: terminal

Recently i encountered a weird problem in Linux mint 14.When i enter any command (e.g `$ ls`) in terminal it throws error saying **Traceback (most recent call last).**

Detail Description  of the error is

```
$ ls

Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 21, in <module>
    os.execvp("python3", [sys.argv[0]] + sys.argv)

 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 344, in execvp
    _execvpe(file, args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 380, in _execvpe
    func(fullname, *argrest)

OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**
```

Same problem appears for all of the command.

Can anyone help me fixing this error